# How to get whole value right after comma in mysql?

Tags: database, mysql-workbench

I have a column in 1 table as shown below. I want to create a query that can get the value after the comma and to the right. For example : if select string 6167 then it will take all rows with value 6167 to the right and if select 67, must have the string "67," to display all information.If the input string after the string does not have a "," then nothing will be displayed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNm58.png

Comment: ask your doubt clearly? do you want to fetch the result with searching number?

Comment: Yes. i want to get all the numbers after the input number is on the right

Comment: there is only way to search the comma separated values in mysql is find_in_set().

Comment: that only get the value, i want to get the whole right part of the input value too

Comment: please post your question with your expected sample answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.